# .NET ASP MVC for/foreach in cshtml does not generate html properly

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

For some reason I am not able to get the expected view.
I am using .Net framework with ASP MVC technology.

In the VIEW (see below) I am trying to upload file with the support of Dropzone.
I upload the files and display them back in the view, leaving the possibility to the user to select the type of document that we just uploaded.

In the debug mode, I can see that all the data are in the returned object, nevertheless, the FOR loop it is not executed - I log the Html and the returned code from the FOR loop it is not present.

Could you help? Do you have any Idea?

Thanks

**VIEW**:

@model ISAA.Models.UploadFileM

...

@using (Html.BeginForm("UploadFiles", "Invoices", FormMethod.Post, new { @name = "myDropzone", id = "myDropzone", @enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
...

```
        <div class="divTable blueTable">
            <div class="divTableHeading">
                <div class="divTableRow">
                    <div class="divTableHead">Uploaded files</div>
                    <div class="divTableHead">Document type</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="divTableBody">
                <div class="divTableRow">

                    @if (Model.UploadedFiles != null && Model.UploadedFiles.Attachments.Count > 0)
                    {
                        for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
                        {
                            <div class="divTableCell">@Model.UploadedFiles.Attachments[i].Name</div>
                            <div class="divTableCell">@Html.DropDownListFor(m => Model.UploadedFiles.Attachments[i].DocumentType, new SelectList(ISAA.Business.Models.Invoices.InvoicesParameters.getInstance().GetDocumentType(), "Code", "Name"), " - Select Document Type -", new { @class = "form-control form-control-sm", aria_describedby = "shipment-entry-19" })</div>
                        }
                    }

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

...

@section scripts {

```
            @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
            @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/dropzone")


            <script type="text/javascript">

                $(document).ready(function () {

                    Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;

                    $('#myDropzone').dropzone({
                        //parameter name value
                        paramName: "files",
                        //clickable div id
                        clickable: '#previews',
                        //preview files container Id
                        previewsContainer: "#previewFiles",
                        autoProcessQueue: false,
                        uploadMultiple: true,
                        parallelUploads: 100,
                        maxFiles: 100,
                        //  url:"/", // url here to save file
                        maxFilesize: 100,//max file size in MB,
                        addRemoveLinks: true,
                        dictResponseError: 'Server not Configured',
                        acceptedFiles: ".cvs,.xls,.xlsx,.pdf",// use this to restrict file type
```

....

}

Comment: Did you check to see if there is data in the loop on page load? You might not have it on page load if it's added afterwards, thus skipping the loop each time.

Comment: Hi! All code under the IF control it is rendered. The word is, I debug the View and the required data is there, but I can confirm that all the data that runs initially it is displayed in the table, all code inside of IF it is not. It looks the page is cached and it reads it over and over. I set a directive in the controller to remove the cache => [OutputCache(NoStore = true, Duration = 0, VaryByParam = "*")] - but the result is the same.

Comment: Have you debugged the controller to see that the model you're passing into the view has data? It sounds like your model is empty, thus not rendering the html in the if/loop block.

Comment: Hi! I have debug. I can see the data. I change the code (just to test). This time I use a basic and simply code : <input type="file" name="files" multiple />. The result was expected. So the problem is in the javascript. I cannot publish here since I only have 300 characters left. Many thanks! I will create a new question with the code that I have.